# Sync Git With Backup Copy

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control

I backed up a copy of an Eclipse project to disc, because my hard drive needed to be wiped. I did not push my changes to git, though.

I am currently using an alternate computer to code the project. I would like to now push the changed files to git. How can I sync this project to the git server without overriding changes, and then push the changed files?

Answer (score 2):

If your backup included the `.git` directory, then you can sync the project the same way you would have done on the original computer. That is, you can do a `git pull` followed by a `git push`.

Additionally, if you have local changes that were not commited, you can add a `git stash` before pulling and conflict resolution.

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop 
# Resolve any conflicts
git push
```

Comment: When I try to push, I get `fatal: unable to access 'http://jaguar.cs[....]aa_code.git/': The requested URL returned error: 500`. Any idea why? Is this something specific to my server?

Comment: @Adam_G, It sounds like your remote URL is out of date, or you don't have push permissions over the `http` protocol, which seems likely. Once you discover a correct URL and protocol, you can just edit the remote path in `.git/config`.

Comment: @Adam_G, If you followed the steps in order, then I take it that your `git pull` was successful. That implies that your git server doesn't accept pushes over unauthenticated http, which is a perfectly reasonable thing for it to do. You most likely need to change to one of the [other protocols](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) which allow writes, such as ssh.

Comment: I actually didn't do a `git pull`. When I did a `git status` it showed all of my files I was going to commit. So I just did an add, commit, and then push. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Git status only looks at local state and doesn't tell you anything about whether your remote is valid. Similarly a local commit doesn't tell you anything about the state of the remote. The common commands for talking to a remote are push pull and fetch.